# Rails ActiveRecord, selecting distinct fields from a joined table and returning all the models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on a Rails app with MySQL.
I have a tables like this:

```
gifts
id, basket_id, orange_id, berry_id

berries
id, action_id, name
```

These are their models:

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :orange
  belongs_to :berry
  ...
end

class Berry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :action
  has_one :gift
  ...
end

class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gifts
  ...
end
```

In the Basket model, I have `gifts` variable that contains all the gifts for this basket, through the association I defined in the Basket model - basically `"SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE basket_id = ?", self.id`

I want to group all the unique `berry actions` for each orange.
Current approach:

```
def get_data
  data = {}
  gifts.each |gift| do
    orange_id = gift.orange_id
    data[orange_id] ||= { :basket_id => gift.basket_id, :name => gift.orange.name, :actions => Set.new }
    data[orange_id] << { :action_name => gift.berry.action.name }
  end
return data
```

My approach was to iterate through `gifts` and save unique `berry actions` into a Set for each unique orange_id, however this approach is slow if I have thousands of gifts with multiple `berry actions` for each berry. If there are 2000 gifts and 4 actions, then I am looping 8000 times.

Gifts can have the same oranges and baskets, but always different berries.

I want to perform this query instead, which will be faster as I will be iterating through unique oranges instead of all the gifts (for each basket there a couple hundred oranges only).

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.basket_id, g.orange_id, g.berry_id, b.action_id 
FROM gifts AS g 
JOIN berries AS b
ON g.berry_id = b.id
```

Can someone show me how to do this using Rails ActiveRecord methods? I would like to be able to iterate through each row of this query and perform actions on the fields I selected. It would also be great if the associated models can be returned as well, such that I can grab the `basket`, `orange`, `berry`, and `action` model for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gifts = Gift.joins(:berry).select(:basket_id, :orange_id, :berry_id, :action_id).uniq.to_a
```

`gifts` will hold an array of gifts with only the attributes specified in `select` initializated:

```
puts gifts.first.attributes
```